# Can I always choose an $N$ such that $\int_{|x|>R}\frac{1}{|x|^{m+N}}dx$ converges?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Given $R>0$ and $m\geq 0$ can I choose an $N$ such that the integral in $\mathbb{R}^n$

$$\int_{|x|>R}\frac{1}{|x|^{m+N}}dx$$

converges? And how can I see this? I am essentially looking for an analogy of $p$-integrals in $\mathbb{R}^n$, ie for what powers does the above integral converge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By polar coordinates $$\int_{|x|>R}\frac{1}{|x|^{m+N}}dx =c_n \int_R^\infty \frac{r^{n-1}}{r^{m+N}}dr =c_n \int_R^\infty \frac{1}{r^{m+N-n+1}}dr$$

which converges if and only if $\color{red}{m+N-n>0}$

Comment: Thanks! So, becuse the function only depends on the radius, the 'angular' terms in the jacobian are all constants, and so their integrals all converge, and so their contribution to the integral is just a constant $c_n$?

Comment: @Laplacinator $c_n =|\Bbb S^{n-1}|$ is the surface of the sphere. Yes it is just theire contribution in the integral